# Recode id in different time spans

Tags: r, data-manipulation, recode, longitudinal

I have longitudinal data on the same individuals across different time spans. How do I assign a new id to the same individual when the time is reset.

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,6,3,4),
                 id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
df
   time id
      1  1
      2  1
      3  1
      4  1
      2  1
      3  1
      4  1
      5  1
      6  1
      3  1
      4  1
```

The expected result is this:

```
  time id
      1  1
      2  1
      3  1
      4  1
      2  2
      3  2
      4  2
      5  2
      6  2
      3  3
      4  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the **time** column is always in order. With `Base R`,

```
cumsum(c(1,diff(df[,"time"])<0))
```

gives,

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Of course you can assign it to the **id** column like,

```
df[,"id"] <-  cumsum(c(1,diff(df[,"time"])<0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R for loop

```
for(i in 2:(nrow(df)-1)){
  df$id[i+1]<-ifelse(df$time[i+1]<df$time[i],df$id[i]+1,df$id[i])
  
}
```